# Android: Simple layout issue

Tags: android, layout

This is probably a simple layout question but I'm being able to get what I want.

I have one LinearLayout (which is horizontal), and I want to display 2 Layouts inside, one on the left, and one of the right (which themselves have overlay, buttons, etc...). I want the right one to ALWAYS be displayed fully, and the left one to be displayed only after the right is completely displayed, if space permit.

**UPDATE**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000111" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this code, only the left side gets displayed. If I change the weight of the first RelativeLayout to 1, then both take 50% of the screen which is what I expect.

What I would please like is the right to take, if needed 100%, and if it takes less then 100%, whatever is left gets used for the left one. How can I do this please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove weight from the right, and set the left's width to 0 and weight to 1:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- ..... -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- ...... -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OK I admit I'm just being picky here and I know `0dp` is functionally the same as `0px` but I'd rather see `dp` as a unit in a layout file than `px`. ;)

Comment: Thanks! Something is still breaking. If I put width of 0px on the elements on left (first) relativeLayout, then only the right side displays. If I put a width of wrap_content, then the left text shows up but the right RelativeLayout doesn't get displayed.

Comment: @Squonk I'm actually the opposite--I put `px` there so I *know* it's meant to be 0. If I put `0dp`, I'd say "... that's not supposed to be zero." Personal preference! ;)

Comment: @user1777907 To ask a stupid question: Are you sure? Make sure the right layout has no weight assigned to it, and that the left does. That's what signals to the OS that adjustment is supposed to take place. If you're still having issues with this exact layout, I can throw it into Eclipse and test it out...

Comment: I'm really sure unfortunately. Let me update the post with more of the layout then. Thanks for the help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: I've updated the code, but there is a lot of styling (some kind of overlays) so I removed that and id's to make it simpler to read. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: It is my second TextView in the first RelativeLayout (which is just plain text) that makes the right RelativeLayout not display.

Comment: @user1777907 Try something out for me: Remove the contents of the `RelativeLayout`s, give them each a different background color, and give the right layout a fixed width (200dp, maybe), to see if the distribution is working without elements. (I can't think of why it would, but boiling the problem down might help.)

Comment: @user1777907 Okay, I think I discovered something. The `android:layout_alignParentRight` attribute on one of the `TextView`s seems to push the layout to be too wide. (As does the `match_parent` width on another `TextView`.) What I'd suggest is perhaps using `LinearLayout`s for each side instead of `RelativeLayout`s. Unfortunately I don't know your exact implementation details so that's as far as my suggestion can go.

Comment: It is indeed working there... weird! I'm going to try to put back one element after another keeping the background, to see where it starts breaking! Thanks!

Comment: Ah good point! Let me check that, I think you solved my problem! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are completely right! The alignParentRight was breaking it! Removing it and it looks like I intend (or very very close, just a few tweaks)! Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate, thanks!

Comment: @user1777907 No problem--glad you've figured it out! :)

Comment: @Eric : I didn't wan't to hijack the comment stream but now the OP has an answer, my point was that with either `0px` or `0dp` together with a `layout_weight`, things are meant to be adjusted dynamically at runtime based on the OP's question. My point against using `px` anywhere in example layout files is that other people might see this Q&A in the future and think it is OK to use absolute screen pixels in general. Use `px` in your own code as a personal preference by all means, just don't teach it as the norm to people who may not know when it is or isn't appropriate. Just how I see it.

Comment: @Squonk Actually, for code on this site, that's a very good point. I think I'll change it... but for my personal code, `0px` stays. ;)